# v2 Function no longer sees function when running

Tags: azure-functions

Had an Azure Function in the v2 preview. It used to work just fine and recently just stopped working without me making any changes. When I run it locally it only shows my Http functions, and if I have no Http functions I'll get an

> No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. config.UseServiceBus(), config.UseTimers(), etc.).

Answer (score 1):

There was a recent release of v2 preview functions [detailed here](http://aka.ms/func2di) which changed how extensions (non-HTTP triggers or bindings) are registered.  You'll need to update the NuGet package extensions for your project.

In C# these are usually something like `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions` like `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs` or `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus`.  It should be at least `beta7` with the last release.

For non-C# projects, you can modify the extension versions to end with `-beta7` in the `.csproj` file in your project root, or run `func extensions install` at the project base which I believe will also auto-upgrade.